# How to compute confidence intervals using the first two moments of a multivariate unknown distribution

Tags: r, confidence-interval, multivariate-analysis

Let assume that we are given the first two moments of an unknown distribution, $\mu$ and $\Sigma$. Since the distribution is unknown and possibly skewed, I do not know how to compute (approximate) confidence intervals if it's possible. If it is not, what could be done using the second moment?

```
mu = c(1, 2)
Sigma = diag(c(2,4))
Sigma[1,2] = Sigma[2,1] = 0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are given the first two **empirical** moments, you can call upon [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality), to create a conservative acceptance region, and then invert the test. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Finite_samples).

If instead of the empirical moments, you are given the population moments, then it is unclear what is the parameter for which you want a confidence interval.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The parameter is the mean of the distribution.